Simple Moving Average Indicator showing angle in degrees
Could you please advise how to write a code to make a 20 period Simple Moving average with showing angle value in degrees between the close price of last 5 (or N) candles close price? i.e. considering x and y vale of last closed candle and the close price of previous 5th (Nth) candle close price,
Look forward to hearing from you
I am a beginner in pine script, i saw angle is reporting in "Line tool" and arrow tool,
but i would like to have same check in box option for a custom made Simple moving average.
i can write code for SMA, but i dont know how to add the math formula to get angle.

You cannot do that because of the price-time scale. The angle will depend on certain things which you have no control over. For example, if you zoom in or out the angle will change. You can even see that with the line tool that you mentioned.
